# Visual Studio xslt debugger adding a breakpoint into xml file

Tags: xml, debugging, xslt, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I'm learning the XSLT debugging in visual studio and on [their webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255606.aspx#Set%20a%20Breakpoint%20in%20an%20XML%20Source%20Document) they mention setting breakpoints into xslt as well as the xml file.

When I do this, the debugger stops at each breakpoint set in the style sheet but at none in the source xml file.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: For example, how can I (or can I) make the code execution pause upon evaluating the value of first author's first-name? Or upon the second check of book genre attribute?

Is that possible by setting breakpoints within the xml file?

Example xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore>
  <book genre="novel">
    <title>The Biography of Herman Hesse</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Hesse</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="sci-fi">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
     <author>
     <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

Example xslt:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book/author/first-name">
        <xsl:if test=".='Herman'">
          <xsl:copy-of select=".."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

    <book-genres>
      <xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book[@genre]">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@genre"/>, 
      </xsl:for-each>
    </book-genres>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Hesse</last-name>
    </author><author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author><book-genres>novel, 
     sci-fi, 
      </book-genres>
```

Comment: Could you share a sample? Like the document you provided, we cannot set a breakpoint on the document node, or on a namespace node that is inherited from the parent element. So if you couldn't set the breakpoint, we would think about that whether it really has this limitation in your xml file.

Comment: Added more info into the post. If I understood it correctly -and VS allowes me to- I can set breakpoints on the individual attribute values (like @genre) or node values (first-name) in the xml. It just doesn't break the execution there.

Comment: Put the mouse on the breakpoint in debugging mode, do you get any warning or error messages? Please also visit the output window to get more information.